# stepcounter, description and lipsum

Tags: counters, value

For some reason I would like a description with a counter.
This works:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{zaehler}

\setlist[description]{style=multiline,labelwidth=2cm,%leftmargin=!, labelindent=0pt
}

\begin{document}
    Zähler: \arabic{zaehler}\\
    \begin{description}
        \item[\stepcounter{zaehler}TOP \arabic{zaehler}] \lipsum[1]
        \item[\stepcounter{zaehler}TOP \arabic{zaehler}] \lipsum[1}]
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

This doesn't:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{zaehler}

\setlist[description]{style=multiline,labelwidth=2cm,%leftmargin=!, labelindent=0pt
}

\begin{document}
    Zähler: \arabic{zaehler}\\
    \begin{description}
        \item[\stepcounter{zaehler}TOP \arabic{zaehler}] \lipsum[zaehler]
        \item[\stepcounter{zaehler}TOP \arabic{zaehler}] \lipsum[\value{zaehler}]
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

How can I get the value of zaehler?

Comment: Use triple backticks ( ``` ) to format code (placing them before and after it). On a German keyboard you can input them with pressing Shift and the ´ key (right to the ß/? key).

Comment: I did, and i used ctrl-k, did not work.

Comment: Only for the next time, ctrl-k did this. Is it different in german?
Using "Shift`+´ "only generates three ``` when i type four times and then deleting  the forth. I cannot create three.

Comment: You can press Shift+´ three times and then hit the space bar. This will create three backticks. You can also mark all the code and click on the `{}` button in the editor. Finally, you can indent all lines of code with four spaces. But you should not use four spaces *and* three backticks.

Comment: Thanks, next time i'll do better.

Comment: As for your question: Try `\lipsum[\arabic{zaehler}]`. You cannot use `\value{counter}` here since it does not print the value of the counter to the output stream.

Comment: you should test your examples. You are missing the lipsum package. Apart from this `\lipsum[\the\value{zaehler}] ` or `\lipsum[\number\value{zaehler}]` (I wouldn't use \arabic, some packages redefine that so that it no longer gives a number). And if you have problems with the backticks: tildes work too, e.g.  `~~~~`

Comment: All three work perfect, thanks very much.

Comment: I might add that the problem is in `\lipsum`.  It should have used something like `\count1=#1\relax` to do the conversion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first optional argument to `\lipsum` wants to see explicit numbers (after expansion) and `\value{zaehler}` doesn't qualify: you should think to it as the abstract number as distinct from any representation thereof.

Instead `\arabic{zaehler}` would work.

I don't think you want to redefine how `description` works nor use such a heavy markup. Better defining a specific environment and a specific command for the items.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{zaehler}

\newlist{topdesc}{description}{1}
\setlist[topdesc]{
  style=multiline,
  labelwidth=2cm,
  %leftmargin=!,
  %labelindent=0pt,
}
\newcommand{\topitem}{\item[\stepcounter{zaehler}TOP \arabic{zaehler}]}

\begin{document}

Zähler: \arabic{zaehler}
\begin{topdesc}
  \topitem \lipsum[\arabic{zaehler}]
  \topitem \lipsum[\arabic{zaehler}]
\end{topdesc}

Zähler: \arabic{zaehler}
\begin{topdesc}
  \topitem \lipsum[\arabic{zaehler}]
  \topitem \lipsum[\arabic{zaehler}]
\end{topdesc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use a list based on `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{zaehler}

\newlist{topdesc}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[topdesc]{
  labelwidth=2cm,
  align=left,
  leftmargin=!,
  %labelindent=0pt,
  label=\usekomafont{descriptionlabel}TOP \arabic*,
  resume,
}

\begin{document}

Zähler: \arabic{topdesci}
\begin{topdesc}
  \item \lipsum[\arabic{topdesci}]
  \item \lipsum[\arabic{topdesci}]
\end{topdesc}

Zähler: \arabic{topdesci}
\begin{topdesc}
  \item \lipsum[\arabic{topdesci}]
  \item \lipsum[\arabic{topdesci}]
\end{topdesc}

\end{document}
```